# Use both enzyme and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, testing

So, we started implementing testing in our app, I used enzyme and my coworkers used react-testing-library. Of course the setupTests.js file is different so either their tests broke or mine. Is there a way to use both or should I migrate the tests and use only one library?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use Jest projects feature for you project for multiple configuration for testing.

Like example:

**Root configuration of Jest**

```
    projects:[
       {
        //react testing configuration
       },
       {
        //enzyme configuration
       }
      ]
```

reference for docs [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them together and incrementally migrate your enzyme tests to react-testing-library.
Update your jest config with path to setupTests.js as:

```js
// other config
setupFiles: ["react-app-polyfill/jsdom"],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/scripts/jest/setupTests.js"],

// rest of the config
```

And in the setupTests.js file, where you'd have configured Adapter for enzyme, add configuration for react-testing-library as:

```js
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { configure as RTLConfigure } from "@testing-library/react";

const TEST_ID = "custom-test-id";
RTLConfigure({ testIdAttribute: TEST_ID }); // if you have a different test attribute for elements on dom

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() }); // enzyme configuration
```

You can find more info on setup [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on your `setupTests.js` just import `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';`